# Override a class' method by iterating over a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass, superclass

This is a complicated problem to explain so I did a crappy MSPaint [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4TC2.png).

[image]

Say I have a list of Subclass objects. Some of them contain a method called `onEvent();`. Inside my `onEvent();` from a completely unrelated class I want to iterate through my list of objects and call their `onEvent();`s if they exist. Obviously if I try to iterate through a list of type Superclass it must be an abstract method to work. I only want a certain few subclasses to have this onEvent() method.

I might have made it hard to understand but I hope you get it, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: All the subclasses would be having onEvent() method you can't prevent inheritance. If onEvent() is not private/static.
**Obviously if I try to iterate through a list of type Superclass it must be an abstract method to work** didn't get this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should rethink your class design.

There are two solutions to your problem

1. Pull the `onEvent` method up into your super class as non-abstract method with empty body. Then you can override in subclasses only where appropriate.
2. Introduce an interface - let's call it `EventHandler` - that declares the method `onEvent`. Implement this interface in your subclasses where appropriate. Then either change your list to be a list of `EventHandler` objects or leave it as is and use `instanceof` to check if an object is an `EventHandler` in your iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In the superclass:

```
// subclasses should override this if they want onEvent to be supported
public boolean isOnEventSupported() {
    return false;
}

public final void onEvent() {
    if (!isOnEventSupported()) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("onEvent is not supported");
    }
    doOnEvent();
}

protected void doOnEvent() {
    // do nothing : subclasses should override this if they want onEvent to do something useful
}
```

Comment: Also possible answer :)

Comment: I think in most of the cases it's disadvantageous to throw an exception if the method is not supported (e.g. when you want to simply iterate over a list and call onEvent). So a simple empty method body should be appropriate and less complex in most of the cases.

Comment: If onEvent returns void, then you can indeed simply do nothing by default. If it's supposed to return something that is not null, then it might not be possible. In this case, having an isOnEventSupported() method allows checking if you can call the method before actually calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

```
interface Listener {
   void onEvent();
}

public class SuperClass {}

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass implements Listener {
    public void onEvent();
}

public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {}

public class DifferentClass implements Listener {
    private final List<SuperClass> objects;

    public void onEvent() {
        for (SuperClass o : objects) {
            if (o instanceof Listener) {
               ((Listener)o).onEvent();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as for me your design is a little messy. I don't know your particular case but usage of `instanceof` is usually smell of bad design!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to make `onEvent` abstract in super class. Then override it with empty body on subclasses that don't support it.